# Browser scale affects on the width

Tags: css

I have a div with fixed width and a special @media rule for width.

**DIV**

```
width: 350px;
```

**@media**

```
@media only screen and (width: 350px)
```

It works fine with next browser scales: 100%, 110%, 150%, 200% and so on.

However, @media rule breaks (not working) for this browser scales: 125%, 175% and so on.

**Questions:**

1. Why does this happen?
2. How to fix this?

**I'm already tried:**

1. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">`
2. `width: 350px; max-width: 350px; min-width: 350px;`

Comment: Can you add a snippet illustrating your problem?

Comment: @WaisKamal What exactly do you mean by that? Image, code sample? I mean, i'm already include all necessary things in the questions. When browser scale is 100% – media rule is working, when browser scale is 125% – media rule is not working.

Comment: 1. probably due to rounding at some point, so that what you _think_ should be an _exact_ value of 350px actually isn’t. 2. by explaining what you actually want to achieve in the first place. Explain how a media query for an _exact width_ of 350px is supposed to make sense in the first place, resp. what you need it for?

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow, a snippet is a code sample that can be run in the same page. You might think the information given is sufficient to identify the problem, but actually, it is not. We need to see what element you are styling, what styles have you applied and what other elements you have in your page.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it, preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Choose **only** `max-width: 350px` for your @media. Your try 2. makes little sense as it will only trigger on exactly 350px and my guess is you want this particular rule to work up to 350px and use another rule from 351px and up.

And yes, the requests for sample code are certainly valid, please comply!